# Solve $2^{1+\sin(3x)}-8^{\sin(x)+\frac13}+\sin (x) \cos (2x)=\sin (x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> I want to solve this equation:
>
> $$2^{1+\sin(3x)}-8^{\sin(x)+\frac13}+\sin (x) \cos (2x)=\sin (x)$$

This is what I did: with $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2 (x)$:

$2^{1+\sin(3x)}-8^{\sin(x)+\frac13}+\sin (x) (1-2\sin^2 (x))=\sin (x)$

$\implies 2^{1+\sin(3x)}-8^{\sin(x)+\frac13}+\sin (x) (1-2\sin^2 (x))=\sin (x)$

$\implies 2\times 2^{\sin(3x)}-8^{1/3}\times 8^{\sin(x)}=2\sin^2 (x)$

$\implies 2^{\sin(3x)}- 8^{\sin(x)}=\sin^2 (x)$

But here I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(3x)=3\sin x-4\sin^3 x$ and $8^{\sin x}=2^{3\sin x}$. Now $$2^{sin (3x)}-8^{\sin x}=2^{3\sin x}(2^{-4\sin^3 x}-1)$$

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake at the second implies. It should be:

> $$\implies 2\times 2^{\sin(3x)}-8^{1/3}\times 8^{\sin(x)}=2\sin^{\color{red}{3}} (x)$$

So you should actually arrive at

$$2^{\sin 3x}- 8^{\sin x}=\sin^3 x$$

Using $\sin 3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3 x$, the equation is equivalent with:

$$2^{\sin 3x}+\frac{\sin 3x}{4}=2^{3\sin x}+\frac{3\sin x}{4}$$

Define the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, f(t)=2^t+\frac{t}{4}$, and the equation is equivalent with:

$$f(\sin 3x)=f(3\sin x)$$

$f$ is clearly increasing, and thus injective. This implies $\sin 3x=3\sin x$ and therefore $\sin^3x=0$, for which the solution is $\boxed{x \in \{k\pi,\ k\in \mathbb{Z}\}}$.